# Converting Apple's MVC Networking sample to ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting, ios5.1

Has anyone converted the Apple MVC Networking sample to ARC?

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MVCNetworking/Introduction/Intro.html

As a new iOS developer I am very interested in ARC and attempted the conversion w/o success, sent a few emails to Apple, no response.

During the conversion there were some CF functions that I couldn't bridge correctly and there were all kinds of memory issues and exceptions.

Currently I don't have an example, just wanted to see if anyone else has been though the conversion, Google didn't help me out this time :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just curious but why are you trying to do this conversion? If you are integrating this example into a project that already runs with ARC, you can exclude the source files that aren't ARC explicitly in the Compile Source section of your build phases in the Target.

If you want to try this, select the sources that don't have ARC and hit enter. A dialog should appear where you can enter:

```
-fno-objc-arc
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The project itself that is using the sample code wasn't converted. Selecting the files and hitting enter didn't work.. nothing happened, really don't want to exclude any files.

Comment: You selected them in the Compile Sources section of the Build Phases tab? That should always bring up a dialog... Here's a screenshot: http://cl.ly/1e2G0g1Z1o2T0q210p1P

Comment: What is the downside in not converting all the code? I am assuming that you have to keep everything inline.

Comment: If the code you are excluding from ARC is a proven library that has been tested and works then there is little downside of using the -fo-objc-arc flag. The main benefits of converting to ARC are less code and reduced risk of defects because you are letting XCode manage that aspect of the code.

Answer (score 1):

XCode 4.3.2 has a new feature to convert projects to ARC.

Edit->Refactor->Convert to Objective-C ARC

Should get you going in no time!

Comment: That is what got me started in this mess :)

Comment: Ooh, gotcha :)  Then you are in over my head as well